# What is the recommended way to write a BufferedImage to a PDF using PDFBox?

Tags: java, bufferedimage, pdfbox

I'm trying to convert a TIFF to a PDF using [Apache Imaging](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/) and [PDFBox](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwiJktvX86PIAhVMmh4KHfRGDrw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpdfbox.apache.org%2F&usg=AFQjCNEbaVW5mOPMt_Nmuv2qxj045bd76g&sig2=qJscV9bR9WU0ua2jL48dtw&bvm=bv.104317490,d.dmo). Everything I've tried results in a blank (but non-zero-byte) pdf.

There are some examples in other SO questions like [Add BufferedImage to PDFBox document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055485/add-bufferedimage-to-pdfbox-document) and [PDFBox draw black image from BufferedImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519866/pdfbox-draw-black-image-from-bufferedimage) which I've tried.

I know the buffered image that I'm reading from the TIFF is valid because I can display it and see it in a JFrame.

I've also tried a PDFJpeg instead of a PDFPixelMap, and contentStream.drawImage() instead of .drawXObject(), the result is always the same.

I also tried creating the PDXObjectImage before the content stream and writing multiple images as recommended in [Can't add an image to a pdf using PDFBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521290/cant-add-an-image-to-a-pdf-using-pdfbox), the result is still the same. The output file is larger when I write the image multiple times, so it's doing "something" but I don't know what it is.

How can I write a BufferedImage to a page on a PDF using PDFBox?

```
try(PDDocument document = new PDDocument();ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) 
{

    PDPage blankPage = new PDPage();
    document.addPage( blankPage );
  //  PDXObjectImage pdImage = new PDJpeg(document, image);
    PDXObjectImage pdImage = new PDPixelMap(document, image);
  //  contentStream.drawImage(pdImage, 5, 300);
    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, blankPage);
    contentStream.drawXObject(pdImage, 5, 5, 100, 100);
    document.save("test.pdf");
    contentStream.close();
}
catch(COSVisitorException ex) {
    throw new IOException(ex);
}
```

Comment: You should do `contentStream.close()` before `document.save("test.pdf")`

Comment: Possibly duplicate of this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31391337/pdf-generated-with-pdfbox-is-blank/31391930#31391930  (you haven't closed your content stream before saving).

Comment: That was it, thank you! Do you want to put this in an answer and I'll upvote you?

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate, but is a subset of the same issue. I think it's a distinct question but if you think it's a duplicate I'm ok with close this as a dupe.

Comment: Bonus hint: download the sources and look for the AddImageToPDF tool. It has a case for TIFF files (but this will only work with G4 compressed TIFFs). It will need jai_imageio (I think).

Comment: IMO it is a duplicate because your PDF is blank. You can upvote the linked issue if you want :-)